# Fortran Code: Is the implementation of PHI function correct?

Tags: fortran

```
  REAL FUNCTION PHI(D) 
  COMMON FAC,DELTA,ER,T 
  DOW=2.*D/DELTA 
  TOW=4.*T/DELTA 
  DOWM=DOW-1. 
  DOWP=DOW+1. 
  IF(D.EQ.0.) GO TO 1 
  PHI=DOWM*ALOG(DOWM)-DOWP*ALOG(DOWP) 
 1-0.5*DOWM*ALOG(DOWM**2+TOW**2) 
 2+0.5*DOWP*ALOG(DOWP**2+TOW**2) 
 3-TOW*(ATAN(DOWM/TOW)-ATAN(DOWP/TOW)) 
  PHI=PHI*FAC/2. 
  GO TO 2 
  PHI=FAC*(0.5*ALOG(1.+TOW*TOW)+TOW*ATAN(1./TOW)) 
  CONTINUE 
  RETURN 
  END
```

My homework is to convert above code into Matlab .m file.

But I couldnt understand and I have never seen an implementation like this:

```
 ....
  PHI=DOWM*ALOG(DOWM)-DOWP*ALOG(DOWP) 
 1-0.5*DOWM*ALOG(DOWM**2+TOW**2) 
 2+0.5*DOWP*ALOG(DOWP**2+TOW**2) 
 3-TOW*(ATAN(DOWM/TOW)-ATAN(DOWP/TOW))
 ...
```

There is not any line continuation mark! This is very confusing.
How should I convert these lines into Matlab code? I know Matlab but I dont know Fortran.

Comment: It looks like this function was copied from [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/sourcecode/book/453805/Crosstalk%20Fortran%20Programs/MSTRP.FOR__.htm) and has suffered in the process (e.g. line labels `1` and `2` are missing).

Comment: I assume this is meant to be source in fixed form, so please pay attention to the indentation of your code (the editor here swallows the first four spaces).  If it is, there are indeed line continuation marks: the `1`, `2` and `3` in column six you've quoted.

Comment: Avoid ALL CAPS, it looks bad in Fortrsn, but it's an old code. But don't use it in new code. Also use space between = operators and parentheses to visually group operations together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PHI** Calculation is in four lines, the **second** line is marked with **1**, and so on ...

Those are ***the continuation marks you are looking for*** (1, 2, 3)

Your formula is:

```
PHI=DOWM*ALOG(DOWM)-DOWP*ALOG(DOWP)-0.5*DOWM*ALOG(DOWM**2+TOW**2)+0.5*DOWP*ALOG(DOWP**2+TOW**2)-TOW*(ATAN(DOWM/TOW)-ATAN(DOWP/TOW))
```

But remember that original Fortran can not understand characters form column 73 and up (only 1 to 72) that is why the use of continuation marks in column 6 (normally is asterisk, but numbers can be used too).

Also code only can be between columns 7 to 72, because columns 1 to 5 are reserved for labels.

My Guess is that ***label 1*** is in front of the second definition of **PHI**, and the ***label 2*** in front of the **CONTINUE**, this is how should look in Fortran

```
   GO TO 2 
1  PHI=FAC*(0.5*ALOG(1.+TOW*TOW)+TOW*ATAN(1./TOW)) 
2  CONTINUE
```

The code in Fortran should be something like this:

```
      REAL FUNCTION PHI(D) 
      COMMON FAC,DELTA,ER,T 
      DOW=2.*D/DELTA 
      TOW=4.*T/DELTA 
      DOWM=DOW-1. 
      DOWP=DOW+1. 
      IF(D.EQ.0.) GO TO 1 
      PHI=DOWM*ALOG(DOWM)-DOWP*ALOG(DOWP) 
     1-0.5*DOWM*ALOG(DOWM**2+TOW**2) 
     2+0.5*DOWP*ALOG(DOWP**2+TOW**2) 
     3-TOW*(ATAN(DOWM/TOW)-ATAN(DOWP/TOW)) 
C
C Previous four (4) lines have this formula (C mark for comment)
C
C PHI=DOWM*ALOG(DOWM)-DOWP*ALOG(DOWP)-0.5*DOWM*ALOG(DOWM**2+TOW**2)+0.5*DOWP*ALOG(DOWP**2+TOW**2)-TOW*(ATAN(DOWM/TOW)-ATAN(DOWP/TOW)) 
C
      PHI=PHI*FAC/2. 
      GO TO 2 
1     PHI=FAC*(0.5*ALOG(1.+TOW*TOW)+TOW*ATAN(1./TOW)) 
2     CONTINUE 
      RETURN 
      END
```

Comment: The confusing part is the jumps **GO TO 1** and  **GO TO 2** because are not shown in your code (labels 1 and 2 should be at column 1 somewhere).  You also have a **CONTINUE** clause but no loop or block, is harmless but apparently there is some missing code here.

Comment: Please if you can, provide original Fortran code to help you better

Comment: A.continue does not require a do loop.